# F# on linux, no prior .NET experience

Tags: f#, functional-programming, mono

Since Semptember I've been playing with Clojure, a functional lisp language on the JVM. I used it in a couple of small hobby projects. The language is very concise, simple, but I came to a conclusion that s-expressions are not really for me.

There are other functional languages out there like Scala, Haskell, OCaml, etc, but they seem to be more of academic languages.

As of late I am considering learning F# in my spare time. I got a couple of questions:

- I am primarily a linux user. I am worried that Mono may be lagging behind.
- I am doing mostly web-dev in a dynamic language which I am pleased with. I'd use F# for some hobby GUI apps, or simple games. Is there good support for both? Can Mono/F# be used for instance on Iphone or Android devices?

When I was learning Clojure I had little Java experience. This didn't turn out to be a big problem. The Java interop was very easy, and Java as a language is also pretty straightforward, so I had no issues reading up documentation.

- Is F#'s interop easy enough, and does the lack of .NET/C# knowledge pose a difficulty in using external libraries?
- Lastly, which resources/books would be adequate for me to learn F# (some functional experience, none .NET/C#)

Thanks

Comment: If I were you I'd use OCaml or Haskell instead. There's a lot more Haskell and OCaml in production than F#.

Comment: They are tempting of course, but there's that one disadvantage that they are not running on any of the major platforms, jvm/net.

Comment: @Rafe: "There's a lot more Haskell and OCaml in production than F#". OCaml, maybe. Haskell, I seriously doubt it.

Comment: Real world functional  programming is a great book!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There has been a lot of progress on getting F# to work well on Mac and Linux:

- In November 2010, the F# team announced an open-source (Apache) release of F# source code. The Mono team is planing to integrate it in the next version of Mono (see [Miguel de Icaza's blog](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Nov-11.html)).
- Folks from Mono already started working on the integration and they have a version with Mono-style Makefiles, which you can [get & build from Github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp). If you don't want to build F# yourself, you can also use [community-created Max/Linux package available here](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/).
- I created an [F# integration for MonoDevelop](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-in-monodevelop.aspx) which gives you pretty good user experience (including tool tips with type information, background type checking and completion).

Regarding interop - F# works pretty well on Mono and should, in principle, run anywhere where Mono works (I would expect Android should work, but I didn't try it). It won't work on iPhone (even though C# works), because there are quite a few limitations in that version of Mono.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of an iPhone/Mono limitation that hampers F# but not C#?

Comment: @Joel: As far as I know, the iPhone version of Mono erases generics in some weird way. I'm not sure if this is up-to-date information (it is based just on a late-night bar discussion with Miguel at F# education workshop :-))

Comment: Why would that affect F# differently to C#?

Comment: The problem seems to be only with generic virtual methods (http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Limitations) not sure whether this affects some core F# functionality or not.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is good enough if you're not trying to ride on the bleeding edge of the hype wave. F# works well with it.

The .NET interop with C-like APIs, using PInvoke, is not difficult to use. It takes some time if you're binding a huge API, tough.

I believe Mono has some iPhone support and don't know about Android support. But I don't work with mobile programming, so, take this with a grain of salt.

For books my personal favorite is [F# for Scientists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470242116) by Jon Harrop. It covers enough material to be interesting even if you're not into scientific computing and it's extremely well written.

Comment: Mono does have iPhone support, see http://MonoTouch.net and Android as well, see http://MonoDroid.net

Comment: "my personal favorite is F# for Scientists by Jon Harrop". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, at least, you'll want to compile Mono 2.8.2 and F# yourself.

I have *Expert F# 2.0* and it is good, too, but I've found that all the other books' authors are active on Stack Overflow!

So far I've used far less C#/.NET with F# than I've had to use Java stuff with Clojure, actually.

F# is very much a Cathedral right now, but it is pretty...